# Returning an Axios Promise from function

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

Can someone please explain why returning an Axios promise allows for further chaining, but returning after applying a `then()/catch()` method does not?

Example:

```js
const url = 'https://58f58f38c9deb71200ceece2.mockapi.io/Mapss'
    
function createRequest1() {
  const request = axios.get(url)

  request
  .then(result => console.log('(1) Inside result:', result))
  .catch(error => console.error('(1) Inside error:', error))

  return request
}

function createRequest2() {
  const request = axios.get(url)

  return request
  .then(result => console.log('(2) Inside result:', result))
  .catch(error => console.error('(2) Inside error:', error))
}

createRequest1()
.then(result => console.log('(1) Outside result:', result))
.catch(error => console.error('(1) Outside error:', error))

createRequest2()
.then(result => console.log('(2) Outside result:', result))
.catch(error => console.error('(2) Outside error:', error))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nandastone/81zdvodv/1/

I understand that Promise methods should return a value to be chained, but why is there a difference between these two return methods?

Comment: the second example returns the "end" of the chain, the first example returns `request` promise

Comment: the real issue is, you are not returning anything in `.then/.catch` - which results in a Promise that will be resolved to `undefined`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, they are returning the result of calling `console.log` - which is `undefined` (I peeked at the fiddle - which isn't a euphemism)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your first example returns the original promise. Your second example returns a *different* promise, the one created by calling `catch`.

The critical differences between the two are:

1. In your second example, you're not passing on the resolution value, so the promise returned by your `then` is resolved with `undefined` (the return value of `console.log`).
2. In your second example, you're converting rejections into resolutions with `undefined` (by returning the result of `console.log` out of `catch`). A `catch` handler that doesn't throw or return a promise that's rejected converts a rejection into a resolution.

One of the key things about promise chains is that they transform the result; every call to `then` or `catch` creates a new promise, and their handlers can modify what's sent downstream as the result passes through them.

The usual pattern would indeed be to return the result of the chain, but for the functions in the chain to either intentionally transform the result or pass it on. Normally, you wouldn't have a `catch` handler except at the terminal end of the chain, unless you're using it to correct the error condition (intentionally converting a rejection into a resolution).

If you wanted to just log what passed through while still allowing callers to see it but *did* want to return the result of the chain for whatever reason, you'd do this:

```
return request
    .then(result => { console.log(result); return result; })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); return Promise.reject(error); });
```

or using `throw`:

```
return request
    .then(result => { console.log(result); return result; })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); throw error; });
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J, your explanation has definitely helped understand chaining promises in more detail. Appreciate it.

Comment: thanks @T.J, you couldn't be clearer. This post helped me with this issue of synchronizing my api calls.