# Cannot get Promise values Return from api from openWeather

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a few problem while integrating api from OpenWeather.

I can successfully log the response data value from the api. But when i call from another component with .then(), throw me the error.

The following is my api.js call with axios

```
function getFiveDayForcast(cityName) {
axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${cityName}&type=accurate&APPID=${apiKey}&cnt=5`)
    .then(function(response){
       // console.log("response" , response.data);
         return response.data;
    })}

module.exports= {getFiveDayForecast:getFiveDayForecast}
```

This is when i call back from my Component

```
componentDidMount(){
        let  city = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).city;
        this.makeRequest(city);
    }

    makeRequest =(city) => {
        //set loading false
        this.setState(()=> ({loading:false}));
        api.getFiveDayForecast(city).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })

    }
```

And it throw

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Would be nice if someone can explain in details about it. I am also reading documentation as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my answer here so more people can see.

Referring to [Returning an Axios Promise from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463989/returning-an-axios-promise-from-function)

The complaint is that a function needs to return something in order for the `then` chain to know what to do.  The function preceding the `then` chain is not returning anything, so the function inside then `then` chain doesn't know what to do.

`Axios` takes care of this for the `get` action, but you aren't directly chaining the `get` method to `then`.  Instead, you are chaining a method you created, `getFiveDayForcast`.

You should change `getFiveDayForcast(cityName)` (btw 'Forecast' is the right spelling) to

```
function getFiveDayForcast(cityName) {

const request = axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${cityName}&type=accurate&APPID=${apiKey}&cnt=5`)
    .then(function(response){
       // console.log("response" , response.data);
         return response.data;
    })
return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the Promise from your Function `getFiveDayForcast`.

```
function getFiveDayForcast(cityName) {
return axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${cityName}&type=accurate&APPID=${apiKey}&cnt=5`)
    .then(function(response){
       // console.log("response" , response.data);
         return response.data;
    })
```

}