# Reactjs: make a function to promise with axios in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, web, axios

I have this function in my **context provider** I want it to **return a promise** so that I can access the returned data from **axios**

```js
    const sendRquest =(service,data,method,url)=>{
        let base = api.find(item => item.name ===service )
        let config = {
            method: method,
            url: `${base.url}/${url}`,
            headers: {
              'x-clientId': clientId,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: data
          };
          axios(config)
          .then(function (res) {
            return res
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return error
          });
    }
```

And the result I'm looking for is to write such code in every other component whenever I needed

```
sendRquest('usermanagement',data,'post','foo/bar').then(res=>console.log(res.data)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463989/returning-an-axios-promise-from-function

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the promise.

Something like

```
    const sendRquest =(service,data,method,url)=>{
        let base = api.find(item => item.name ===service )
        let config = {
            method: method,
            url: `${base.url}/${url}`,
            headers: {
              'x-clientId': clientId,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: data
          };
        return axios(config)
          .then(function (res) {
            return res
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return error
          });
    }
```

Be careful tho because you are "swallowing" errors by using `.catch` like this. The promise returned by `sendRquest` will never "fail" (reject) but will succeed (resolve) with either data or error payloads.

Answer (score 0):

the complete answer is like this

may help you all

```
 const sendRquest =(service,data,method,url)=>{
        let base = api.find(item => item.name ===service )
        let config = {
            method: method,
            url: `${base.url}/${url}`,
            headers: {
              'x-clientId': clientId,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': token
            },
            data: data
          };
        return axios(config)
    }
```